# transitive closure over a symmetric relation in prolog

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I am a prolog beginner and I want to create the "brother" relation.

The relation should be symmetric as in if **brother(alin, alex)** is true, **brother(alex, alin)** should be as well.

It should also be transitive as in if **brother(alin, alex)** and **brother(alex, claudiu)** are true, **brother(alin, claudiu)** should be as well.

Combining the to properties, if **brother(alex, alin)** and **brother(alex, claudiu)** are true, **brother(alin, claudiu)** should also be true.

Here is my code:

```
r_brother(alin, alex).
r_brother(alin, ciprian).
r_brother(alex, claudiu).

s_brother(X, Y) :- r_brother(X, Y).
s_brother(X, Y) :- r_brother(Y, X).

brother(L1, L2) :-
    t_brother(L1, L2, []).

t_brother(L1, L2, _) :-
    s_brother(L1, L2).

t_brother(L1, L2, IntermediateNodes) :-
    s_brother(L1, L3),
    \+ member(L3, IntermediateNodes),
    t_brother(L3, L2, [L3 | IntermediateNodes]).
```

**r_brother** - is the basic relation

**s_brother** - is the symmetric brother relation(**this works well**)

**t_brother** - this should be the transitive and symmetric relation, I keep the intermediate nodes so I don't get a loop

The problem is that the answer for:

```
?- brother(X, alin).
```

is:

```
X = alex ;
X = ciprian ;
X = alin ;
X = alin ;
X = alin ;
X = alin ;
X = alex ;
X = alex ;
X = alex ;
X = alex ;
X = ciprian ;
X = ciprian ;
X = claudiu ;
X = claudiu ;
false.
```

I looked through the trace and I understand what the problem is, but I don't know how to solve it.

**alin** should not be a possible answer and the others should appear a single time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the basic problem is that you do not check if L2 is already found in the first clause of t_brother/3. And the initial L1 should be added to the list in brother/2:

```
brother(L1, L2) :-
  t_brother(L1, L2, [L1]).                   % <-- [L1] instead of []

t_brother(L1, L2, IntermediateNodes) :-
  s_brother(L1, L2),
  \+ member(L2, IntermediateNodes).          % <-- added this check

t_brother(L1, L2, IntermediateNodes) :-      % <-- this clause is unchanged
  s_brother(L1, L3),
  \+ member(L3, IntermediateNodes),
  t_brother(L3, L2, [L3 | IntermediateNodes]).
```

You can still shorten the solution by using a disjunction:

```
t_brother(L1, L2, IntermediateNodes) :-
  s_brother(L1, L3),
  \+ member(L3, IntermediateNodes),
  ( L2=L3
  ; t_brother(L3, L2, [L3 | IntermediateNodes])).
```

Comment: Just so I understand, in "(L2=L3 ; t_brother(L3, L2, [L3 | IntermediateNodes]))" - does this mean that if the first condition(L2=L3) is true it doesn't need to do verify the second condition?

Comment: No, it is a simple disjunction `(AlternativeA;AlternativeB)`. Either `L2` is the next brother `L3` or we find a `L2` by calling t_brother recursively. Maybe you have confused it with the `(Condition -> Then ; Else)` statement which implies a local cut?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the brother relation like this (exactly like the transitive definition)

```
s_brother(X, Y) :- r_brother(X, Y);r_brother(Y, X).

brother(X,Y) :- s_brother(X, Y).
brother(X,Y) :- s_brother(X, Z),s_brother(Z, Y),X\=Y.
```

which mean X is brother of Y if he is a symmetric brother, or they have a brother in common, and add the condition that they are different.

try adding to X\=Y to your code to get rid of "alin" as a solution.

Comment: thanks, this is a lot shorter :), but the problem here is that if you add another fact like r_brother(claudiu, jack).  you will not get "jack" as an answer. This has to be recursive to work.