# family relation in Prolog Query :transitive relations

Tags: prolog, lisp, allegrograph

I have information in AG knowlwedgebase like this

```
 Person1 hasBrother Person2
 Person1 hasSister Person 3
```

How can I write a rule in prolog to find out additional relations from the the above facts

```
Person2 hasSister Person3
Person3 hasBrother Person2
Person 3 is SiblingOf Person 2
```

I have tried like this  but no success:

```
(<-(Family ?p1 relation ?p2)
(q ?p1 !ns:hasBrother ?p2)
(q ?p1 !ns:hasSister ?p2)
)
```

Can anyone help me out to write a rule to get additional transitive relations?

Comment: The code that you "tried" (`<-(Family ?p1 ...`) doesn't look like any Prolog I've ever seen before. So it's unclear to me what you're asking for.

Comment: this is actually rule syntax when we use prolog under lisp

Comment: The query calls  AG knowledgebase data. ok If you give me hint how we can find transitive  relations in simple prolog syntax  then I can convert into the above rule syntax. your help would highly be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What you need has been asnwered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539327/transitive-closure-over-a-symmetric-relation-in-prolog)

Comment: thanks vmg   got idea